# javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder parse quietly not possible?

Tags: java, xml, dom

The `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder` prints a message in `std:err`.

Example below:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class FooMain {

    public static Document slurpXML(String s) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document rv = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        return rv;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        try {
            slurpXML("foo");
        } catch (Exception e) {} // try to silence it - in vain
    }
}
```

Despite the try-catch block, running the program from the command line produces:

```
$ java -classpath dist/foo.jar FooMain 
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

I want to use `DocumentBuilder` in a console utility and I don't want the output to be cluttered. Is there a way to silence it?

Comment: A more general solution is to redirect stderr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a custom ErrorHandler that does nothing

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

public class FooMain {

    public static Document slurpXML(String s) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        builder.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
            @Override
            public void warning(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {

            }

            @Override
            public void error(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {

            }

            @Override
            public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {

            }
        });
        Document rv = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        return rv;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        try {
            slurpXML("foo");
        } catch (Throwable e) {} // try to silence it - in vain
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding the default `ErrorHandler` on `DocumentBuilder`

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#setErrorHandler%28org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler%29

Another option since DOM as part of `JAXP` is a set of standard APIs, you can always try specifying an alternate implementation of the DOM parser that has the behaviour you are looking for.